# When I try to define settings, I get a different error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const settings = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('../settings.yml', 'utf8'));
const {car} = require('./car-bmw.js');

function log() {
    console.log("Car name:" + settings.space + car.name);
    console.log("Car model:" + settings.space + car.model);
    console.log("Car color:" + settings.space + car.color);
};

try {
    log();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`${settings.errorMessage}`);
    console.error(error);
}[e][1]
```

When I try to run this script, I get the error `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './settings.yml'` and `Process exited with code 1` . Anybody can help?

[image: directory,folder]

Comment: Then what’s the current directory if not `src`? `process.cwd();`.

Comment: Better use `path.join(__dirname, '../settings.yml')`

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what the current working directory is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is incorrect in the filesync, you can use path.join

```
var fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const path = require('path');

// file will be picked up if it is in same directory
// else you need to provide the relative path and path.join will 
// create a correct path for it

const settings = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/settings.yml'), 'utf8'));
const {car} = require('./car-bmw.js');

function log() {
    console.log("Car name:" + settings.space + car.name);
    console.log("Car model:" + settings.space + car.model);
    console.log("Car color:" + settings.space + car.color);
};

try {
    log();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`${settings.errorMessage}`);
    console.error(error);
}[e][1]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help. 
Now I get the error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined`

Comment: Added the path module from node.js. You can now check the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. But now i get the error `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'source\settings.yml'` [directory](https://i.imgur.com/Z4XW7RM.png)

Comment: `const path = require('path');
const settings = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(path.join('source', '/settings.yml'), 'utf8'));`

Comment: Can you add the directory structure of the file you want to read and the script which reads it?